# Submit input button styling

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make css style for `input type="submit"` button same like this style for `nav` bar buttons???

```css
nav {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  grid-area: nav;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav li {
  padding: 13px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0.3em;
  background-color: #000000;
  bottom: -0.9em;
  transition: all ease-in-out 350ms;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
}

nav li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Domů</a></li>
    <li><a href="switcher.php">Fun Switcher</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Radio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fotky</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to do this styling?

Comment: `input[type="submit"] { /* styling goes here */ }`

Comment: `::before` and `::after` selectors don't work with `<input />`. So you need to use a `<button></button>`